# Keep common js functions in a file to be used throughout application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have Rails app using Asset Pipeline. There are many js files associated with different parts of the app. To keep it DRY I want to start pulling some of the repetitive code into a file and use those methods throughout the app. What I am attempting right now isn't working.

common.js.coffee

```
common =
  some_commonly_used_method: ->
    // code
```

Some_other_page_speciific_file.js.coffee

```
common.some_commonly_used_method()
```

browser console when I load the page

> Uncaught ReferenceError: common is not defined

What do I need to do to have common.whatever available throughout the app?

Comment: Did you set up your app for page specific assets? By default, any JS/Coffee function you define is already available to all pages, regardless of the file in which you've defined it.

Comment: I didn't set the app up. I came on about 2 years after. Honestly, I'm not sure how one would set it up to be page specific or not, but that seems to be the way things work. to your statement, regardless the methods don't seem to be able to be accessed globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting it in the window object ended up being my solution. I'm not sure it's ideal, but it works.

common.js.coffee

```
window.common =
  some_commonly_used_method: ->
    // code
```

Some_other_page_speciific_file.js.coffee

```
window.common.some_commonly_used_method()
```